# Return paramater after form submission (in custom module)

Tags: module, forms

I am building a custom module. In my module I have a form function which basically creates the form.

When this form is submitted, I want the form to return to a specific URL.

I have added a 'RET' hidden field to the form with the correct URL, but I am unsure how to have the form actual use this.  Can anyone show me what I need to add to my existing code to achieve this.

```
public function form() 
{
    $entry_id = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('entry_id');
    if( $entry_id === FALSE ) {
        return "";
    }

    $return = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('return');

    $hidden_fields = array(
        "entry_id" => $entry_id,
        "ACT" => $this->EE->functions->fetch_action_id( 'Cdwd_waiting_list', 'submit_record' ),     
        "RET" => $return   
    );

    $form_data = array(
        "id" => $this->EE->TMPL->form_id,
        "class" => $this->EE->TMPL->form_class,
        "hidden_fields" => $hidden_fields
    );

    $tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->tagdata;

    $form = $this->EE->functions->form_declaration($form_data) . 
        $tagdata . "</form>";

    return $form;           
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of your `submit_record` method (of your `Cdwd_waiting_list` class), you'll need to add something like this (after you've done everything else you need to with the form submission):

```
ee()->functions->redirect(
    ee()->input->post('RET')
);
exit();
```